# how to make the external content inside the bootstrap 3 modal responsive.

Tags: responsive-design, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 for modal box.I am using i frame to load external content using `data-src` attribute.

```
<div class="container">
   <a class="modalButton" data-toggle="modal" data-src="http://www.sitepoint.com/" data-height=320 data-width=450 data-target="#myModal">Click me</a>

   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
           </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
              <iframe frameborder="0"></iframe>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
         </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
     </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
</div>
```

It works perfectly,But the
 external site is not responsive inside the modal.

If i open the site in the browser its responsive, and working good.

Already there is a demo for this `data-scr`, please check it

Thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/2AU6q/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the size of modal as the entire page by settingheight and width of the modal and the iframe as 100%. This might work. If you give height and width in pixel it will never be responsive